# Adding multiple CSV files to ArcGIS Pro all at same time

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, csv

I have a folder of CSV files and I was told to add all of the CSV files at once into ArcGIS Pro. The CSV files are all formatted the same way, they include latitude, longitude, depth and time.

Is there a way I can add all of the CSV files into ArcGIS Pro at the same time instead of adding them individually?

Comment: Have you tried multiple selecting them in the Windows Explorer and dragging and dropping them into a map view or the Contents pane?

Comment: Do you really mean just adding them all to ArcGIS Pro at the same time (in which case @PolyGeo has the answer in his comment).  Or do you mean adding them all in such a way that they are all merged into a single table?  (Since, as you say, they all have the same schema.)